# Removing Characters With the Jquery Keydown Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the keydown function, how would I remove the beginning characters entered into a form.

For example, I have an form `<input>` that collects a website address. the website address has `http://` entered with it.  As the user types their domain, I use the Keydown function to enter what they are typing into a `<P>`. But I want the `http://` removed from the `<p>`

This is how I am using the keydown function

```
    //<![CDATA[ 
       $(function(){
       $('#Website').keydown( function(){
         var str = $(this).val();
       $("#viewer").text(str);
       });
   });//]]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen `keyup` event. It's also important to remember to catch `paste` event as well:

```
$(function () {
    $('#Website').on('keyup paste', function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var str = $(self).val();
            $("#viewer").text(str.replace(/^http\:\/\//, ''));
        }, 0)
    })
});
```

*(setTimeout is needed because sometimes paste is not fired immediately, so little delay fixes it)*

http://jsfiddle.net/fL6vt/

Comment: Good point I did not think of that, what about an autofill event?

Answer (score 0):

your string replace to replace http:// with '' blank before you  put it in

```
//<![CDATA[ 
       $(function(){
       $('#Website').keydown( function(){
       var str = $(this).val();
       str = str.replace("http://",""); 
       $("#viewer").text(str);
       });
   });//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/vGXvU/

```
 $('#Website').keyup(function () {
     var str = $(this).val();
     if (str.indexOf("http://")==0) {
      str=str.substr(7);   
     }
     $("#viewer").text(str);
})
```